# How is proper uck link working ? ( - link is somehow broken )

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

Hello when fetching datas with :

> sudo apt-get update

then all links work except the link of uck respectively of uck-tool.

the message output is then in German like here:

> `Es wurden 2.138 kB in 10 s geholt (205 kB/s).
>
>   W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://ppa.launchpad.net/uck-team/uck-stable/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found`

How is the proper link of uck named to be typed without mis-spelling ?!
thank you.

Comment: Define `uck` you mean `ubuntu customization kit`? Also I see your ppa is for vivid, this release went end of life this month, what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @markkirby - hi, yes ubuntu customization kit to create *.iso - file ... but vivid is not at end of life ?! I installed 14.04 and upgraded to 15.04 with updates to kind of LTS3 (LTS 4 soon) - vivid will be maintained until 15.04.06 ( like 12.04.02 was until 12.04.06 ) - and uck is working here - only update-link is somehow broken ... so I installed synaptic too and xfce4 ... at moment unity is a bit lousy again ...

Comment: Vivid is 15.04 and that went eol on 1st of jan 2016 it is not an lts, the current lts releases are 12.04 and 14.04, the next one is 16.04, 15.04 is not lts and its time is up. Please see this page http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life If you are running 15.04, you need to upgrade to 15.10.

Comment: Anyway the fix to your issue is, open this file, `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the line referencing `ppa.launchpad.net/uck-team/uck-stable/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources` now purge `uck` and use the version in the default repos, but this won't work either as 15.04 is end of life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely normal, as there is no package for Ubuntu Vivid in that PPA. See http://ppa.launchpad.net/uck-team/uck-stable/ubuntu/dists/.

Remove the PPA from your repository list and find a different package source for UCK.